# Change the End behaviour of CSS3 Rotate Transitiion

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a rotate(360deg) CSS transition on a button with the default css being rotate(0deg).

When the class applying that rotate(360deg) value is no longer present the browser auto rewinds **back** to the default rotate(0deg).

With the animation going clockwise by default I would rather the end behaviour was to carry on clockwise to the default 0 rather than rolling back (anti-clockwise).

Can I specify this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can yet, not that I know of anyway. I tried to get something similar myself. Pretty sure Jquery will get the job done, I haven't done this practically but it should just be something like

```
$("#container").rotate({
```

bind: 
     { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:360})
        },

```
 }
```

});

**EDIT** Sorry, it's a JQuery plugin, not included in it. Here's a link http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

**SECOND EDIT** Think I've solved it using key frames. Put this anywhere in your css file:

```
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
0% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
} }
```

Then put this in your hover action thingy:

```
.button:hover{
-webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
}
```

Should do what you want, worked for me.

Comment: I should have been clearer. I want a CSS transition solution or nothing :-) If it cannot be done yet then fair enough

Comment: I don't think edits send notifications so I hope this does, got it sorted using just css3.

Comment: i have only just seen your update. I am already using keyframes, only difference is my duration is 1s not 0.5s and iteration count is infinite. I did switch to iteration count of 1 but that did not fix it. thanks for trying though